# динамическое добавление полей javafx

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

есть форма (javafx без fxml, GridPane с -мя колонками: лэйбл и поля для ввода) . Необходимо реализовать добавление полей (например добавить несколько дат). При нажатии на кнопку добавления строка должна дублироваться. Далее данные из полей ввода считываются и передаются в метод другого класса для последующей обработки.

`bild(String stringName, String stringNumber, String stringDate)`

Как передать в другой класс динамическое количество срингов? Ну или как вообще такое реализовывают обычно?

Comment: `bild(String... strings)`, что эквивалентно `bild(String[] strings)`

Comment: Думала о массиве. Тогда получается что сперва он динамически наполняется, а в другом классе будет обращение к элементам и их обработка?